# Number of enol forms of acetylacetone

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers, tautomer

**Here is what I tried:**
[image]

These are the two enolic forms that I could make. So according to me, the total number of distinct enol forms of acetylacetone is $2$. But the answer is 3, what am I missing?

Comment: Write the formula of acetylacetone, this time including *all* hydrogen atoms bound to the molecule.  Then, write down reaction equations for the equilibria between acetylacetone and its tautomeric enols; again with all hydrogen atoms bound to the molecule.

Comment: In practice, you're not missing anything. Dienols aren't really viable in practice, for this compound. Even your unconjugated tautomer is hardly important. Then again, if you push into dienols, then there is even fourth one, with two double unconjugated bonds. Either ways this answer is wrong.